# Regex: Select the content of tags without some words, until |

Tags: regex

I have more tags. And I want to Select their content without some words, and to replace with something else. For example:

`<title>WORD_1 WORD_2 | Blahhhhhh<title>`

`<title>WORD_3 WORD_4<title>`

`<title>WORD_5 WORD_6<title>`

`<title>WORD_7 WORD_8 | Dammmmmm <title>`

The desire select for replace:

- `WORD_1 WORD_2`
- `WORD_3 WORD_4`
- `WORD_5 WORD_6`
- `WORD_7 WORD_8`

Or, in other terms, I want to select all content of tags until the second part (until `|`)

Comment: What language are you using?

Comment: notepad++ windows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could accomplish this using the following *regex* ...

```
(?<=<title>).*?(?=\||<title>)
```

- `(?<=<title>)` looks behind for `<title>`
- `.*?` matches any charecter
- `(?=\||<title>)` looks forward for `|` or `<title>`

see **[regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/bT3msr/1)**

**EDIT 1 :**

To keep only the words until `|` and delete all the tags ...

***search with :*** `.*?(?<=<title>)(.*?)(?=\||<title>).*`

***replace by :*** `$1`

**EDIT 2 :**

To keep only the words after `|` and delete all the tags ...

***search with :*** `.*?(?<=\|)(.*?)(?:\||<title>)`

***replace by :*** `$1`

Comment: and what will be vice-versa? If I want to keep only the words until `|` and to delete all <title> tags?

Comment: and again, the last case, if I want to delete all tags and keep only the words after `|` ?

Comment: nope, the last regex doesn't work. Maybe You forgot to select the first open tag?

Comment: @RobRob yes, it does work. do you wanna also replace `<title>WORD_3 WORD_4<title>` and `<title>WORD_5 WORD_6<title>` ?

Comment: yes, sure, ohh, boy. I forgot to write in my example, that after `|` there are 2 word, not only one like `Blahhhhhh`. So, if there is only one word after `|` your regex works.

But if there are many words after `|` ?

Answer (score 0):

While the previous answer is good I would suggest  ***faster***(optimized) regex pattern:

```
(<title>).+?(?=\||<title>)
```

**https://regex101.com/r/8gCnCy/1**

---

*Performance comparison:*

with *PHP(PCRE)* flavor:

`(<title>).+?(?=\||<title>)`    - **4 matches, 260 steps (~229ms)**

`(?<=<title>).*?(?=\||<title>)` - **4 matches, 433 steps (~288ms)**

---

with *Python* flavor:

`(<title>).+?(?=\||<title>)`    - **4 matches, 370 steps (~270ms)**

`(?<=<title>).*?(?=\||<title>)` - **4 matches, 973 steps (~529ms)**